# Is it possible to limit the memory a process uses from command line?

Tags: bash, memory, process, memory-management, memory-limit

Is it possible to limit the amount of memory a process consumes from the command line and eventually automatically kill the process if it tries to overpass this limit?

Something like

```
MaxRam -4GB ./MyProcess args
```

For your information, I am on `Mac OSX Version 10.11.3`.

Comment: On Linux there is a `ulimit` command which allows control over the resources "on systems that allow such control" (`help ulimit` or `man bash` for information), but I don't know if the limit extends to any or all subprocesses launched; if not OSX may have system programs to specify the limits on a program as it is run, but this would not be a `bash` internal command.

Comment: more answers/comments can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12268925/limit-memory-allocation-to-a-process-in-mac-os-x-10-8) -- it seems like there is no way to do this (please feel free to correct me!)